# Web Scraping in Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, scraper

I have been using Python's Beautiful Soup library to scrape pages, however I am running into a few limitations. I am scraping different (usually news) websites all the time and do not know ahead of time what the outline of the site is like. Ideally, I would like a function that just grabs the main text off the website (not the linked headlines to other articles). I have noticed that the text usually lies within the `<p>` tags of websites but it is not always the case so I created this function:

```
def get_text(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    text = ""
    for node in soup.findAll('p'):
        inner_node = node.findAll(text=True)
        for inner_text in inner_node:
            text += ' ' + inner_text
    return text
```

However, it does not work all the time and I often miss items. I would assume that there must exist something that is already made that I can use instead and/or a few best practices to follow when grabbing text. I would appreciate your guidance on the matter.

Comment: Have you tried the .stripped_strings generator?

Comment: I honestly would recommend looking into RSS for the news sites. The format is much more standard than trying to deal with HTML. With HTML, you can have either `<p>` or `<div>` tags with content, either of which could be irrelevant to the main content. To do this at the HTML level, you would most likely need per-site configuration describing the mapping of tags to content.

Comment: Tyler M., I have not! And I will do!